# In fallout 4 is it possible to get a 100% chance to ignore damage from an attack if you collect all the unstoppables magazines?

Tags: fallout-4

Is it possible to get a 100 percent chance of not taking damage in fallout 4 if you collect every issue of the unstoppables?

Comment: I don't even know if there are enough unstoppables comics in the game

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! One of the upvote/downvote criteria is prior research. I'm not upvoting due to lack of research, and I imagine that's what the downvotes are for. A quick Google search would have found: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Unstoppables You should usually check that wiki before you get to the next step of asking a Fallout question here.

Answer (score 8):

No, there are only 5 [Unstoppable](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Unstoppables) magazines, for a total of 5% damage reduction.

Comment: But can you use an item duplication glitch to get 100 of them?

Comment: @Adonalsium it doesn't matter, each magazine adds a level to the unstoppable perk, the perk maxes out at 5